# Dragon Quest Heroes Best Money Farm Method

Tags: ps4, dragon-quest-heroes

What is the best method for money farm in DQ Heroes?

Comment: I edited the tags. It may be important to note that on weekends an event that rewards extra items, exp, and gold runs (and this may influence what the best farm method is for that time period).

Comment: I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-0czndLC-c
It's a method for coins and money farm. Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: I can't watch at work, sadly, but feel free to post that as an answer to your own question. I'd certainly upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I have found this video:

It's a method for coins and money farm. What you need to do is equip Bianca with the Allure ring, Raging Ruby, Ace of Spoils and her weakest weapon, and go for that spot.

If you do that in weekends that's a plus, since we have money and drop boost at weekends.

Comment: Why weakest weapon? Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have a better drop rate or crit change if you use her weakest weapon.. I've not played this game for a long time, so I'm not sure about that.